# not able to update the extjs Panel Toolbar items

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Not able to update the toolbar items when i am getting data from ajax.

// to get the toolbar items from the ajax
    var  getQuickAccessVal;

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '/me/module/edit/treeapi/quick',
   success:  function (response) {    
     getQuickAccessVal = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
     console.log(getQuickAccessVal );
     TW.toolbar.doLayout();
   }
 });
```

//Adding ajax response to Toolbar

```
TW.toolbar =  new Ext.Toolbar({
  width: 'auto',
  enableOverflow: true,
});

 TW.toolbar.add(getQuickAccessVal);
```

//adding toolbar to panel

```
TW.TreeToolPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    width    : 'auto',
    height   : 'auto',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    id:'treeContent',
    html:'<iframe id="content" name="content" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>',
    autoScroll: true,
});
TW.TreeToolPanel.add(TW.toolbar);
```

Comment: can you add a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)?

Comment: what is the result of your console.log(getQuickAccessVal); ?

Comment: the problem is: not able to update the response json data with the Toolbar.do I need to reload the Toolbar after response?

Comment: try to call `doLayout()` on toolbar

Comment: I need to add items dynamically after the toolbar has been constructed.

Comment: How is the code structured, how do those 3 small pieces relate to each other? The timing is important.